# Pythagorean type diophantine equation.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> How to find all solutions to
>
> $$ a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=e^2+2$$
>
> where all variables $a$ to $e$ are positive integers and $e^2 \equiv 1 \mod 8$

I tried using parameterization similar to pythagoras equation, but no success so far. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions. Take any natural number for $e$ and use the four-square-theorem, which states that each natural number (here $e^2+2$) can be written as a sum of four squares.

Comment: @sranthrop I also suspected that, but how can we find a parameterization that covers all the cases?

Comment: Now, since squares are either 0,1, or 4 mod 8, we must have that exactly three of the squares are 1 mod 8 and the remaining one is 0 mod 8..., but there are still infinitely many solutions.

Comment: what is the source of the problem? why would anyone want to know all solutions?

Comment: @Will Jagy It was in one of my advanced level worksheets.

Comment: Then I suggest you write a computer program, odd $e$ up to some small bound (say, 21) and then sums $0 \leq a \leq b \leq c \leq d$ that solve the equation. Maybe there is some severe restriction that appears, giving very few answers, in which case a full parametrization becomes possible.

Comment: @sranthrop To apply the four square theorem needs more work, since in that theorem some of the squared numbers may be $0$ but OP requires positive $a,b,c,d,e.$

Answer (score 3):

For such equations, you can use the standard approach. 
One approach is to use equations Pell.  For the beginning will talk about a more simple way.

**I. Eq.1**

$$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=(2q+1)^2+2$$

Solutions have the form:

$$a=x + k$$

$$b=x + p$$

$$c=x + s$$

$$d=x - z+1$$

$$q=x$$

where,

$$x = -1 -z+ (z^2 - k p - k s - p s),\quad z = k+p+s$$

for any $k,p,s$.

**II. Eq.2**

$$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=(4q+1)^2+2$$

Solutions have the form:

$$a=2(y + k)$$

$$b=2(y + p)+1$$

$$c=2(y + s)+1$$

$$d=2(y - z)-1$$

$$q=y$$

where,

$$y = -k + 2z + 2(z^2 - k p - k s - p s),\quad z = k+p+s$$

for any $k,p,s$.

**III. Eq.3**

$$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=(8q+1)^2+2$$

Solutions have the form:

$$a=16k^2+4p^2+4s^2+8pk+8ks+4ps+2s+2p-1$$

$$b=16k^2+4p^2+4s^2+8pk+8ks+4ps+4s+4p+8k$$

$$c=16k^2+4p^2+4s^2+8pk+8ks+4ps+4s+6p+4k+1$$

$$d=16k^2+4p^2+4s^2+8pk+8ks+4ps+6s+4p+4k+1$$

$$q=4k^2+p^2+s^2+2pk+2sk+ps+s+p+k$$

$k,p,s$ - integers asked us.

Comment: Individ: I simplified two of your formulas, and checked them with *Mathematica*. I hope it's ok.

Answer (score 3):

Now will show you a different approach. For,

$$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=(2q+1)^2+2$$

One can use the *Pell equation*,

$$x^2-ry^2=1$$

where,

$$r =k^2+(t^2+p^2+s^2)+(t+p+s)^2$$

for **any** $k,t,p,s$. Let,

$$u = x-2(t+p+s)y,\quad w = x-(t+p+s)y$$

Then solutions are,

$$a=2\, k\, u\, y$$

$$b=q - 2\, t\, u\, y + 1$$

$$c=q - 2\, p\, u\, y + 1$$

$$d=q - 2\, s\, u\, y + 1$$

$$q=2\,u\,w$$

And another solution:

$$a=2k(2(t+p+s)y-x)y$$

$$b=2y((p+s)x+(2(t^2+2(p+s)t+ps)-k^2)y)+1$$

$$c=2y((t+s)x+(2(p^2+2(t+s)p+ts)-k^2)y)+1$$

$$d=2y((p+t)x+(2(s^2+2(p+t)s+pt)-k^2)y)+1$$

$$q=2y((t+p+s)x+(2(tp+ts+ps)-k^2)y)$$

Be aware that if the ratio of the Pell equation $r$ - fold the square, can be reduced. In the formula, too, should be reduced.

Comment: I simplified your first solution and checked it with _Mathematica_.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII thank you.

Comment: @individ Does your parameterization generate all solutions?

Comment: @Samurai I know exactly one.  All these formulas together give all the solutions. But this is not a significant issue. More important to know how to obtain these solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile, there certainly is an answer of sorts using stereographic projection. It has the virtue of seeming to be a parametrization in four new letters along with $e.$ Weakness is that solution quadruples may not always be primitive. Nope, stereographic needs homogeneous, does not apply here.

I do not see enough of a pattern to suggest a recipe for all solutions. $(0,1,1,e)$ always works, furthermore one number is divisible by 4 and the other three are odd, that is about it.

```
    e       a    b    c    d
    1       0    1    1    1

    3       0    1    1    3

    5       0    1    1    5
    5       0    3    3    3
    5       1    1    3    4

    7       0    1    1    7
    7       0    1    5    5
    7       1    3    4    5

    9       0    1    1    9
    9       0    3    5    7
    9       1    3    3    8
    9       3    3    4    7

   11       0    1    1   11
   11       0    5    7    7
   11       1    3    7    8
   11       1    4    5    9
   11       3    4    7    7
   11       3    5    5    8

   13       0    1    1   13
   13       0    1    7   11
   13       0    3    9    9
   13       0    5    5   11
   13       1    1    5   12
   13       1    5    8    9
   13       3    3    3   12
   13       3    4    5   11
   13       3    7    7    8
   13       4    5    7    9

   15       0    1    1   15
   15       0    3    7   13
   15       0    5    9   11
   15       1    1    9   12
   15       1    8    9    9
   15       3    4    9   11
   15       3    5    7   12
   15       4    7    9    9

   17       0    1    1   17
   17       0    1   11   13
   17       0    7   11   11
   17       1    1    8   15
   17       1    3    5   16
   17       1    4    7   15
   17       1    5   11   12
   17       3    7    8   13
   17       4    5    5   15
   17       4    5    9   13
   17       5    8    9   11
   17       7    7    7   12

   19       0    1    1   19
   19       0    5    7   17
   19       0    5   13   13
   19       0   11   11   11
   19       1    3    8   17
   19       1    4   11   15
   19       1    5    9   16
   19       1    7   12   13
   19       3    4    7   17
   19       3    4   13   13
   19       3    7    7   16
   19       3    8   11   13
   19       5    5   12   13
   19       5    7    8   15
   19       7    7   11   12
   19       7    8    9   13

   21       0    1    1   21
   21       0    1    9   19
   21       0    7   13   15
   21       1    3   12   17
   21       3    3    5   20
   21       3    3    8   19
   21       3    3   13   16
   21       3    8    9   17
   21       3   11   12   13
   21       4    9   11   15
   21       5    7   12   15
   21       5    9    9   16
   21       7    9   12   13
    e       a    b    c    d
```

---